# Does daemon() have any disadvantages?

Tags: c++, c, linux, daemon

Does using the C function [`daemon()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) have any security or stability disadvantages for a linux daemon compared to using explicit functions like `fork(), setsid(), umask(),` etc. (beside being unable to set all daemon parameters)?

I was wondering why I should write

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    //Set our Logging Mask and open the Log
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog(DAEMON_NAME, LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Entering Daemon");

    pid_t pid, sid;

   //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) 
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //Change Directory
    //If we cant find the directory we exit with failure.
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //Close Standard File Descriptors
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    while (true)
    {
        sleep(5);

        //Do something
    }

    closelog ();
}
```

instead of

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    daemon(0, 0);

    while (true)
    {
        //Do something

        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: What is confusing about this question? Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: I'd tend to suggest writing *neither*, or at least making it optional at runtime. Self-daemonizing software is unnecessarily difficult to work with in the context of modern best-practices process supervision (which has the parent process watching for a SIGCHLD and automatically restarting, notifying monitoring systems, or taking whatever other outcome is configured). If you daemonize, your parent doesn't *get* that SIGCHLD at all (or, rather, gets it much too early) and needs to poll to determine if/when exit really happens (and can't access exit status, signal type, etc post-exit).

Comment: According to the man page, `daemon()` _at least_ does not handle logging via `syslog()`.

Answer (score 3):

Per the manpage, it's not in POSIX so you're always taking a risk regarding its existence.

Otherwise, no.